# Splunk - stop break-by by timestamp

Tags: splunk

Sorry new to Splunk...I've a single logfile with entries that look like this:

"15/11/2017 20:20:59","0","1803.xml","Copied to Amazon S3",5,"O"
"15/11/2017 20:21:00","0","1260.xml","Copied to Amazon S3",5,"O"
"15/11/2017 20:21:00","0","2415.xml","Copied to Amazon S3",5,"O"
"15/11/2017 20:21:01","0","134.xml","Copied to Amazon S3",5,"O"
"15/11/2017 20:21:01","0","808.xml","Copied to Amazon S3",5,"O"
"15/11/2017 20:21:02","0","261.xml","Copied to Amazon S3",5,"O"
"15/11/2017 20:21:02","0","646.xml","Copied to Amazon S3",5,"O"
"15/11/2017 20:21:03","0","1157.xml","Copied to Amazon S3",5,"O"

Splunk is breaking this into events by timestamp (field 1) but because the above entries have repeating timestamps I only get the first event for each date.

How can I insure that EACH line gets its own event?

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a new sourcetype with
1. SHOULD_LINEMERGE = false
2 removed BREAK_ONLY_BEFORE attribute

and point the data source to this

Answer (score 0):

In the Splunk Professional Services world, we call these "Base Configs" and these should be applied to ALL new data sources coming in. You tie base configs with the sourcetype, so below you would replace my_sourcetype with your sourcetype.

In most cases, SHOULD_LINEMERGE should be set to false AND you should use line_breaker rather than break_only_before. If your in a small environment, your current settings *may* work decently, but when you start scaling, your indexers will be overloaded.

Apply these on `props.conf` on your indexer(s)

```
[my_sourcetype]
TIME_PREFIX = \"
MAX_TIMESTAMP_LOOKAHEAD = 25
TIME_FORMAT = %d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S
LINE_BREAKER = ([\r\n])\"\d+\/\d+\/\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+\"
SHOULD_LINEMERGE = False
TRUNCATE = 10000
```

Comment: Don't forget to restart Splunkd after making these changes!